# Converting binary string to hex in PHP

Tags: php, binary, hex

I have a string of binary text which is a multiple of 8 characters long. Take the following for example.

```php
$fullNameBin = "01010001000010110110010000010011000110000111100011001011111110110100111100111100";
```

I wish to convert this to hex. Note that the bits of each byte are in least significant to most significant order, so the above should result in

```php
$fullNameCoded = "8AD026C8181ED3DFF23C";
```

In Perl, this can be achieved using

```perl
my $fullNameCoded = "";
for ( unpack( '(A8)*', $fullNameBin ) ) {
   $fullNameCoded .= sprintf( "%02X", oct( "0b" . reverse( $_ ) ) );
}
```

or

```perl
my $fullNameCoded = uc unpack 'H*', pack 'b*', $fullNameBin;
```

PHP's pack/unpack is much more limited than Perl's, and a naive translation was unfruitful.

```php
foreach ( unpack( "A8*", $fullNameBin) as $item ) {
   $fullNameCoded .= sprintf( "%02X", octdec( "0b" . strrev( $item ) ) );
}
```

Comment: Consider breaking the code in both languages into smaller steps so you can print debug output for every individual instruction, to see where it's going wrong.

Comment: In case it helps, the Perl code can be simplified to `my $fullNameCoded = uc unpack 'H*', pack 'b*', $fullNameBin;`.

Comment: @ikegami Do you know the PHP equivalent of that?

Comment: I don't know PHP

Comment: I question why you have a binary string in the first place. Seems like the code took a step backwards that needs to be undone.

Comment: The unpack strings are different. Maybe that's the impact?

Comment: @Markus Zeller, Well yes, but `(A8)*` is not something understood by PHP's unpack

Answer (score 0):

What I did is splitting the binary string representation into 8 chars, reversed it and created the hex representation from it and uppercased them.

```
$fullNameBin      = "01010001000010110110010000010011000110000111100011001011111110110100111100111100";
$fullNameCoded    = '';
foreach(str_split($fullNameBin, 8) as $char) {
    $fullNameCoded .= strtoupper(dechex(bindec(strrev($char))));
}
```

gives

```
8AD026C8181ED3DFF23C
```

I may be totally wrong, please anyone correct me:

For me it looks like the unpack "A8*" can get 8 characters from the string, but is not capable of repeating until end when a number is given.

- "A*" will give the whole string.
- "A8" will give 8 chars
- "A8*" will give also only 8 and **does not repeat**.

#### Conclusion

I think it does not work with unpack, because `$fullNameBin` is **not binary**, but a **string representation** of the binary data.